# Extend $.getScript to enable cache locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, getscript

What is the correct way to extend jQuery's getScript method to enable cache only inside that function for the ajax request?

I need to use this in my application to avoid unnecessary request for various scripts. Also is it correct to override this method or should I name the new function differently.

What I came up with is

```
jQuery.getCachedScript = function( url, callback, options ) {
    // Allow user to set any option except for dataType, cache, and url
    options = $.extend( options || {}, {
        dataType: "script",
        cache: true,
        url: url,
        success: callback
    });

    // Use $.ajax() since it is more flexible than $.getScript
    // Return the jqXHR object so we can chain callbacks
    return jQuery.ajax( options );
};
```

using the example form https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/. Is it correct, and can I name this getScript to override the jQuery method.

Would it be preferred to instead of using

```
cache: true
```

(or additionally) to use a global array that stores the .js files URLs and check against it for every call. I wrapped all the javascript code in this files in a function that I can call with different arguments using the getScript callback.

Comment: I would prefer the way you've done it.

Comment: Any reason not to change the default? `$.ajaxSetup({cache: true});`. This would cache other AJAX requests, though, so you'd need to watch out for that.

Comment: Anyway, I would probably use a new method name (like your example) if it was me. jQuery plugins might occasionally use `$.getScript`, and I can't think of any reason a plugin should break if caching was enabled, but it's not impossible.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I used other ajax request in the same script, for backend generated data that may change and I didn't have the time to do cache invalidation logic. As a sidenote, I've just recently started working again at this project after a long break and I have to say, that after acquiring so much more experience using JS I wish I'd made the effort to port the old codebase that I got form my colleagues to some kind of framework + AMD/RequireJS when I posted the question here,.. but it's too late now :(.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy good point that I could possibly break other plugins. I use other jQuery ajax plugins (for file downloads, and server/client data validation) and I didn't think about that. The code remained as is written in the example anyways. Thanks!